# Provide parameter SchemaType for XmlObject

Tags: java, xmlbeans

I have a class like

```
public class CreditCardDocumentImpl extends org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.values.XmlComplexContentImpl implements creditcard.CreditCardDocument
{

   public CreditCardDocumentImpl(org.apache.xmlbeans.SchemaType sType)
   {
       super(sType);
   }
}
```

That class is implementing "CreditCardDocument" interface.

The interface is like

```
public interface CreditCardDocument extends org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlObject
{
```

Now, if I want to access that constructor as

```
CreditCardDocument creditCardDocument = new CreditCardDocumentImpl(CreditCardDocumentImpl.class.instanceType());
```

It throws as error,

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: static creditcard.impl.CreditCardDocumentImpl.instanceType() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
```

I'm not getting what is the error. What could be the parameter that I need to pass to the constructor?

Comment: The constructor is asking for a `org.apache.xmlbeans.SchemaType` or `SchemaType`.

Comment: Yes. What should I pass to the method?  In this line of code CreditCardDocument creditCardDocument = new CreditCardDocumentImpl(CreditCardDocumentImpl.class.instanceType());

Comment: a [SchemaType](https://xmlbeans.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/reference/org/apache/xmlbeans/SchemaType.html)

Comment: CreditCardDocument creditCardDocument = new CreditCardDocumentImpl(SchemaType); Thats all?

Answer (score 6):

Did you generate these classes through CXF using XmlBeans? If so, probably your interface provides a public static property with the schema type, or even better, you can try:

```
CreditCardDocument creditCardDocument = CreditCardDocument.Factory.newInstance();
```